# query related to BigDataBench benchmark and simplescalar tool and gem5 simulator

Tags: bigdata, benchmarking, analysis, gem5

I want to analyze  BigDataBench benchmark or any other benchmark related to big data using the simplescalar simulator tool or gem5 simulator.

I have successfully installed simplescalar simulator with gcc2.7.2

Can anyone please tell me how I can analyze big data benchmarks using simplescalar simulator or gem5 simulator?

Can anyone please tell me how I can analyze big data benchmarks using simplescalar simulator or gem5 simulator?